# Does Angular has CDN Link?

Tags: angular, cdn

Does Angular have CDN link?
So, to start the quick development of the Angular project with Angular CDN?

For example, when you are working with Vue.js for quick check or playground you can use Vue CDN -
https://vuejs.org/guide/quick-start.html

Comment: Did you consider Angular CLI? You can create template project with one command.

Answer (score 0):

You can use StackBlitz (https://stackblitz.com/) in order to create an Angular "Playground" (you can even create Vue.js projects).

Of course there are different options available (like https://codesandbox.io/) but StackBlitz seems to be the most popular one.